# is there a way to show 'order table and customer table' to one dataGridView?

Tags: c#

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stack<Customer> customer = new Stack<Customer>();
        Stack<Order> orders = new Stack<Order>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=true";
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Top 5 ContactName,Freight from Orders,Customers WHERE Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID ORDER BY Freight DESC;", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Customer c = new Customer();
                c.ContactName = (string)reader["ContactName"];
                Order o = new Order();
                o.Freight = (decimal)reader["Freight"];
                orders.Push(o);
                customer.Push(c);
            }
           
            con.Close();
        }
       
        dataGridView3.DataSource = customer.ToList();
        dataGridView4.DataSource = orders.ToList();
    }
```

I'm trying to get top 5 users name and detail using Stack but I can't show both orders and customer table to one datagridview

Comment: Yes, but some or none of the columns will be editable. If you need them editable, use two grids, a dataset, two datatables, a datarelation between them and a pair of bindingsources, one bound to the parent table and the other bound to the datarelation exposed by the parent bindingsource. Also consider that a grid is a rectangle, and your data is 1:many; it'll necessarily become a mash of data where the parent stuff repeats over and over, once per child

Comment: *I can't show both orders and customer table to one datagridview* - a datagridview only has one source of data. If you want it to show data from two sources, e.g. two tables, you have to combine the data into one source.. i.e. make a CustomerOrders object with the props you want, generate instances, set the props, and add them to a collectionthat you will show in the grid.. Either that or invoke your query there using a DataAdapter and fill a datatable with it, then set the datasource of the dgv to the datatable

Comment: Read up on what an ANSI92 join is; it's been possible to avoid (and we've been striving to avoid) writing joins in the way you've done there for 30 years now

Comment: Finally, please rename your controls after you drop them on a form; it takes seconds to do and means your code doesn't end up practically obfuscated. You have the luxury of being able to nip into the form designer and check whether it's textBox47 or textBox74 that is the username textbox, but someone on the internet helping you does not have this luxury. Even having the form and doing lookups quickly gets boring and is a huge waste of your time, compared to taking 2 seconds out to change the name to `"usernameTextBox"` after adding the control to a form